# Recommended C/C++ General Purpose DSP Libraries

Tags: software-implementation, c, c++

I am looking to transition some of my MATLAB algorithms to C/C++ for deployment on target (PowerPC and/or ARM).  Mostly 1D FIR/IIR filter in this instance.

In other domains, there are well-regarded general libraries (both speed and quality) with liberal licencing. For example, Linear Algebra has [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) and [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (amongst others), and computer vision has [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).

There are well-regarded libraries for specific algorithms, such as [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/), but what about a collection of general algorithms for 1D signals?

I'm not after DSP-specific libraries, such as for [PIC32](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en552827), [CMSIS (ARM Cortex M4)](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/index.html), [DSPLIB (C64x)](http://www.ti.com/tool/sprc265) or [Renesas](http://am.renesas.com/products/tools/middleware_and_drivers/c_splib/a_dsp/index.jsp), but nonetheless has similar functionality.

Comment: I've heard very good things about [liquid DSP](http://liquidsdr.org/), but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: I'll be frank and say that my library is not "well regarded" in the sense that hardly anyone knows about (i.e. it is not "regarded" at all :-) ), but it has lots of 1D DSP functionality.  If you do find bugs in it, please let me know and I will be happy to fix them.  https://github.com/JimClay/NimbleDSP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a bit late, but since others might land here like me.

The following are good signal processing libraries/frameworks:
  * https://www.gnuradio.org/ - lots of classic signal processing + cascading options
  * https://root.cern.ch/ - advanced statistical signal processing
Both provide generic facade, fall-back implementations as well as performance optimised sub-libraries (ie. fftw, atlas, LAPACK, gsl, VOLK, ...).

Together with OpenCV, these probably cover 90++% of use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Matlab Coder/Embedded Coder/Simulink Coder toolboxes from Mathworks to convert Matlab/Simulink to C/C++. They work well. The code is easy to read and you can navigate from C/C++ to Matlab easily in the code generation report.

Pros :

- The code is easy to read.
- Integrates almost seamlessly with your code base.
- Portable.

Cons :

- Slightly slower than hand-written code
- Expensive

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way of converting MATLAB code to C/C++ that I found Armadillo: http://arma.sourceforge.net/license.html. It's a C++ library covering various categories such as signal and image processing, statistics, matrix and vector, etc. For implementing a FIR filter for example, one can use the convolution (`conv(A,B)`) function.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard good things about eigen:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

If you are on iOS I would look at:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp

It is possible to call Matlab from C. But hardly portable or something you do for a product.

I have reimplemented parts of Matlab several times («a good Matlab programmer can write Matlab in any language»). It would have been nice to have a open source/debugged C library mirroring the core Matlab function signatures. Then we could focus on getting 0-based and 1-based counting, column-major vs row-major, Visual Studio not supporting C99/ complex float, and all of the other pifalls :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not [CMSIS DSP](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS-DSP/latest/index.html) on [github](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-DSP) Other that nimbledsp and liquid dsp mentioned in comments.